# Using of map or Max by in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I am solving a leet code problem. I found one question in leetcode, which are below

You are given an `m x n` integer grid accounts where `accounts[i][j]` is the amount of money the **i​​​​​​​​​​​th**​​​​ customer has in the **j​​​​​​​​​​​th​​​​** bank. Return the **wealth** that the richest customer has.

A customer's **wealth** is the amount of money they have in all their bank accounts. The richest customer is the customer that has the maximum **wealth**.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: accounts = [[1,5],[7,3],[3,5]]
Output: 10
Explanation: 
1st customer has wealth = 6
2nd customer has wealth = 10 
3rd customer has wealth = 8
The 2nd customer is the richest with a wealth of 10.
```

I tried my solution which is fine

```
class Solution {
    fun maximumWealth(accounts: Array<IntArray>): Int {
        var highestSum = 0 
        for (i in 0 until accounts.size) {
            var sum = 0 
            for (j in 0 until accounts[i].size) {
                sum += accounts[i][j]
            }
            if (sum > highestSum) {
                highestSum = sum
            }
        }
        return highestSum
    }
}
```

I went to discuss section and I found two new solution. One is using **[map](https://leetcode.com/problems/richest-customer-wealth/discuss/1237321/Kotlin-one-liner)** and another one is **[maxBy](https://leetcode.com/problems/richest-customer-wealth/discuss/1099500/Kotlin-1-line/1024791)**

**MAP**

```
accounts.map { it.sum() }.max()
```

**MAXBY**

```
accounts.maxBy { it.sum() }?.sum() ?: 0
```

I am curious which solution is better Is mine or any of this two or all are same? I know my solution **Time complexity:** `O (M x N )` and **Space complexity:** `O(1)`.

1. So which one is better?
2. Someone explain me how map is working?

Many Thanks

Comment: "MAP" first creates a list of wealth per each account and then looks for max. So it has the same time complexity, but it requires additional O(M) space. "MAXBY" is a little weird, because it first searches for the account with the biggest wealth and then calculates its wealth again. Technically, it has the same time and space complexity to your solution, but it performs one additional sum for one account. BTW, this problem can be solved with simple: `accounts.maxOf { it.sum() }`. Internally, it works in a very similar way to your own code.

Comment: there is better solution `accounts.maxOf { it.sum() }` or `accounts.maxOfOrNull { it.sum() } ?: 0` if accounts can be empty

Comment: At least one of those comments should probably be an answer :-) (Not least, so that it'll hang around for posterity even if the comments get moved to chat or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

`map` takes a collection of items, does something to each item and puts the result in a new collection, producing another collection with the same number of items

So in your example, each item is an array of `Int`s. What do you do with each array? You're running `sum` on it, which basically adds up all those ints, and your result is the total - each value in your collection is being *mapped* to another value

```
[1,5] --mapping function-->  6
[7,3] --mapping function--> 10
[3,5] --mapping function-->  8
```

If it helps, the mathematical concept here (the simple version, I'm no expert in this stuff!) is that one one side, you have the space of all possible input values. In this case, all the possible `Int` arrays that could exist. On the other side, you have the space of all the `Int` values that represent the possible totals for all those arrays

The *mapping function* is there to *map* every possible value in the input space, to its corresponding value in the output space. You give it an input value, and it points at a specific output value. That's where the term *map* comes from.

It's like a keyboard mapping in a game - you set it up so that when you press a certain input key, that's *mapped* to a specific event. The overall mapping is all the input keys that could be used, and what they should be translated to. A *mapping function* is like that, except your set of possible inputs and outputs can be a lot larger! But it still defines a specific result for each possible input. And when you call `map`, you're using that function to transform each of your inputs into its corresponding output

Comment: Great explained thanks you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, you have an array whose elements are themselves arrays. Remember that `map` applies the function you give it to each item. So,the array of arrays is transformed into an array of the sums of each array and then you find the maximum of those.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. Can you please explain by example. I tried so many times to understand the use of `map` but I always failed. Could you please explain with example?

Comment: You provided us with an example. It might be useful to tell us what you're finding difficult to understand.

Comment: Also, I will try and fill in some more details when I can - assuming I can find an online Kotlin REPL, as I won't be at a computer the next few days.

Comment: I understand now @cactustictacs explained very well. Thanks once again